# Any way to configure specific hosts to resolve specific domains in /etc/resolv.conf?

Tags: linux, domain-name-system

When I use `OpenVPN`, the DHCP service on the VPN host sends back the IP addresses of DNS servers I should use to resolve hosts on the vpn subnet:

```
nameserver 10.14.16.13
nameserver 10.14.16.84
search vpn.corp.net
```

The problem is, now I cannot resolve hosts on my own `192.168.1.0/24` LAN (foo.localdomain) where `192.168.1.40` is my `dnsmasq` server.

Is there a way to configure `/etc/resolv.conf` to resolve `vpn.corp.net` using the `10.14.16.x` DNS hosts but use `192.168.1.40` to resolve everything else?

Comment: for the specific host `vpn.corp.net` you can add entry in `/etc/hosts` - `<ip address> <hostname>`, however I don't think what you're asking for is achievable, not unless you install a dns server on your machine and configure it in that way.

Comment: I agree with @13nilux  You need a recursive server on your openvpn host, then tell it what recursors to use for specific domains.  I've used `Unbound` for this purpose.

Comment: yeah, I've never found a good way to solve this problem without standing up some sort of local DNS server. `dnsmasq` does have a way to specify a forward for a specific domain (`server=/vpn.corp.net/10.14.16.13`). Just wanted to check that there wasn't an easier way to do this without having to recommend an extra service to setup for everyone.  However, doing this in `dnsmasq` also means if the DNS servers for the vpn ever change, `dnsmasq` has to be reconfigured. Won't be automatic like DHCP metadata.